# Genetic algorithm - problem with inheritance

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I have implemented a genetic algorithm to fit polynomial that should divide 2 sets of points. I generate first random population and results seem to be as desired, but the problem starts to grow when I cross population. I think I messed something up with crossovers or with 'fitness function'. In the first run, the program finds good solutions, but every iteration it gets worst.

Example of 1 iteration:
[image]

Example of last iteration:
[image]

The function that I use to check how good polynomial is.

```
def evaluation_mutation(points, population, degree):
    temp = convert_to_dec(population, degree)
    result = []
    counter = []
    counter2 = []

    for inx2 in range(len(temp)):
        counter.append([])
        counter2.append([])
        for i in range(len(points[0])):
            if (np.polyval(temp[inx2], points[0][i, 0]) < points[0][i, 0]) and points[1][i]:
                if not counter[inx2]:
                    counter[inx2] = 1
                else:
                    counter[inx2] = counter[inx2] + 1

            elif (np.polyval(temp[inx2], points[0][i, 0]) > points[0][i, 0]) and not points[1][i]:
                if not counter2[inx2]:
                    counter2[inx2] = 1
                else:
                    counter2[inx2] = counter2[inx2] + 1

        if counter2[inx2] and counter[inx2]:
            result.append([counter[inx2], counter2[inx2]])
        else:
            result.append([])

    return result
```

Complete code : https://pastebin.com/u5rr62QV